# self.context['request '].user always returns AnonymousUser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am trying to get current user in a model serializer

```
self.context['request'].user
```

but it always returns AnonymousUser.
Here is the serializer code snippet

```
class QuestionBlockDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    isvoted = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_isvoted(self,obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        print self.context['request'].user
        ...
```

Below is the settings for permissions and AuthBackends

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',)

 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

),
```

view:

```
class QuestionBlockDetailAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
   permission_classes =[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
   serializer_class = QuestionBlockDetailSerializer
   queryset= Question_Block.objects.all()
   lookup_field = 'q_slug'

   def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.destroy(request,*args, **kwargs)

   def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.update(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

I tried adding Session and BasicAuthentication but it always returned AnonymousUser. Please help me on this.

Comment: can you show your views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` permission class in your `QuestionBlockDetailAPI` view. So unAuthenticated users have read access to your api. Therefore `self.context['request'].user` is AnonymousUser when unAuthenticated user accesses you api.

you can solve this by changing you  `def get_isvoted(self,obj):` method like:

```
def get_isvoted(self,obj):
    if self.context['request'].user.is_authenticated():
        return self.context['request'].user.isvoted
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I get anonymous for authenticated users also. I am using oAuth with token authentication. I tried the above snippet. It still returns anonymousUser

Answer (score 0):

Just use user.is_authenticated in condition

```
if self.context['request'].user.is_authenticated:
    return true
```